# Why my webservice runs in localhost but doesn't run in my host on the internet?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I wrote a simple web service and published it, then upload it in my host. There is a folder with name "webservice1" in my host, beside other files of my web site.

In folder "webservice1" I upload 2 files: myclass_Service1.asmx and web.config and a folder bin which has dll files.

But when I type the address of my webservice in the URL, it isn't recognized.
I also upload files in root of my host, but they also aren't recognized.

In my local host it will run, but on my host it doesn't
Why?

thanks

Comment: Please share the error you are getting when trying to browse to webservice url.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly does your Browser say?

Sounds like a Firewall issue to me:

- Open the "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security"
- Choose the "Inbound Rules"
- Search for Rules including "WWW-Services" or Similar
- Make sure to Activate the Rules allowing Port 80 (and 443 for https)

Screenshot (Sorry for german):
[Windows Firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpQAO.png)